# Force full expansion of a token

Tags: expansion

I have an aliased verbatim command (specifically lstinline) e.g.

```
\def\verbalias{\lstinline[morekeywords={thing}]}
```

Next I have a few commands that I want to use both in text and in my verbatim command e.g.:

```
\def\foo{thing}
\def\inner#1{inner #1}
\def\outer#1{outer \inner{#1}}
```

Now what I want to write the following commands:

```
\def\formattedfoo{\verbalias!\foo!}
\def\formattedinner#1{\verbalias!\inner{#1}!}
\def\formattedouter#1{\verbalias!\outer{#1}!}

% test cases
\formattedfoo
\formattedinner{thing}
\formattedinner{\foo}
\formattedouter{thing}
\formattedouter{\foo}
```

Now of course none of these work in the way I would like for obvious reasons.

So instead I tried

```
\def\formattedthing{\expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\foo!}
\def\formattedinner#1{\expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\inner{#1}!}
\def\formattedouter#1{\expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\outer{#1}!}
```

Which works for the first two test cases but fails for the rest.

The solution I have found:

```
\def\formattedinner#1{%
    \edef\tmp{\inner{#1}}%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\tmp!
}
\def\formattedouter#1{%
    \edef\tmp{\outer{#1}}%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\tmp!
}
```

What I would like to write is:

```
\def\formattedinner#1{%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\expandfull{\inner{#1}}!
}
\def\formattedouter#1{%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\expandfull{\outer{#1}}!
}
```

Is there a better way to force expansion other than an edef? Is it possible to write a `expandfull` macro?

Note I am not interested in:

```
\def\expand#1\as#2{%
    \edef#2{#1}%
}
\def\formattedinner#1{%
    \expand{\inner{#1}}\as{\tmp}%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\tmp!%
}
```

edit full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\inner#1{inner #1}
\def\outer#1{outer \inner{#1}}
\def\verbalias{\lstinline[morekeywords={thing}]}

% Working syntaxes
\def\foo{thing}
\def\formattedthing{\expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\foo!}

\def\expand#1\as#2{%
    \edef#2{#1}%
}
\def\formattedinner#1{%
    \expand{\inner{#1}}\as{\tmp}%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\tmp!%
}

\def\formattedouter#1{%
    \edef\tmp{\outer{#1}}%
    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\tmp!%
}

% Desired syntax
% \def\formattedinner#1{%
%    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\expandfull{\inner{#1}}!%
% }
%
% \def\formattedouter#1{%
%    \expandafter\verbalias\expandafter!\expandfull{\outer{#1}}!%
% }

\begin{document}

\formattedthing

\formattedinner{thing}

\formattedinner{\foo}

\formattedouter{thing}

\formattedouter{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as remember, `\lstinline` is from `listings` package. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: My question is agnostic to `\lstinline` feel free to substitute `\verb`

Comment: no, lstinline like all verb commands can not be used in the argument of another macro, so any answer for lstinline is more restricted than a general command. but perhaps you are looking for `\expanded`

Comment: My question is about forcing macro expansion, lstinline is a case study.  But I will edit with a full example.

Comment: `\expanded` forces expansion, if the commands are expandable. so is I think what you want for `\expandfull`

Comment: Can you link to any documentation for expanded?  It works but it is not mentioned in TeXbyTopic or TheTeXbook.

Comment: `texdoc pdftex`  or `texdoc luatex` originally an unreleased pdftex extension, has always been in luatex and is now in pdftex, xetex and ptex

Comment: Erm, are you sure you want to use the name `\outer` for one of your macros? The reason I ask is that the name `\outer` is already in use -- for a TeX primitive, no less. (See p. 206 of the TeXbook, for instance.) Reusing this name sounds like an open-ended invitation to swift and absolute disaster.